# incompatible SDK for ARC with mac osx 10.10

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, swift

I am getting annoying warning messages for my targets after upgrading to osx 10.10, and the latest xcode (I can't remember which actually triggered it)

e.g: Incompatible SDK for ARC in target ApplicationName: macosx

If I change it from 'latest' to '10.10' then I get the same error:

Incompatible SDK for ARC in target ApplicationName: macosx10.10

Everything works and compiles, but still warning.  The code is mixed swift and objective C, with ARC.  Anyone else had this issue?

Comment: is your xcode updated to the latest? (6.1)

Comment: yes it is the latest

Comment: Same problem here. I get this warning for right away after creating a new project.

Comment: I have a question, do you use any of the older SDKs (i.e. have you installed them in xcode)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had some older SDKs (10.5 and 10.6) from previous xcode versions that I had saved, in the xcode SDKs directory, which seemed to cause this error.  I deleted these and replaced them with fresh ones downloaded from the apple website and the error went away.

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem. But I found a solution:
In the Build Settings turn off the "Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting" paramter.

Comment: Alas I use ObjC arc in other parts of the program...  Do you use any of the older SDKs? (see above question in comments)

Comment: I didn't paying attention to this, sorry.